# Как установить безопасные атрибуты yii 2?

Tags: php, yii2

Работаю с базовой версией.
Собираю данные с формы и хочу записать их в базу массово, через атрибуты. 
Вот мои правила валидации:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['name', 'date', 'parking_place', 'parking_time','spent_fuel', 'remain_fuel', 'distance'],
            'required', 'message' => 'Поле не может быть пустым'],
        [['parking_time','spent_fuel', 'remain_fuel', 'distance'],
            'integer', 'message' => 'Значение должно быть целым числом'],
        [['name', 'date', 'parking_place', 'parking_time','spent_fuel', 'remain_fuel', 'distance'],
            'safe'],
    ];
}
```

Вот так я пытаюсь записать данные в базу:

```
$model->attributes = Yii::$app->request->post();

$fleet = new Fleet();
$fleet->attributes = $model->attributes;
$fleet->save();
```

В массиве $model->attributes есть все значения, а вот в $fleet->attributes есть только названия полей, без значений.

Comment: Сдается мне, что всё же надо писать так `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());` и тогда в атрибутах будет то, что нужно..... и даже лучше `if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))` ибо может ничего и не загрузиться

Comment: `if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {<br>
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('reportFormSubmitted');

            $fleet = new Fleet();
            $fleet->attributes = $model->attributes;
            $fleet->save();

            return $this->refresh();
        }`

Comment: Вот так у меня это и записано. Я не могу присвоить атрибуты из $model в $fleet

Comment: `Вот так у меня это и записано.` - зачем же сбивать с толку тогда, располагая в вопросе другой код? .......`Yii::$app->session->setFlash('reportFormSubmitted')` - как она может быть `Submitted` если ты не сделал `$model->save()` ? ............. пробуй загрузить атрибуты вот так: `$fleet->setAttributes($model->attributes);`

Comment: [Вот](http://joxi.ru/v29GBVVc8y4zrG) я поменял код. И по прежнему в атрибутах есть только названия полей.

Comment: Ещё поправка. Объекты $model и $fleet от разных классов. И валидация формы происходит в $model. Кстати, разобрал вот так:
`$attr = $model->attributes;
            $fleet->name = $attr['name'];
            $fleet->date = $attr['date'];
            $fleet->parking_place = $attr['parking_place'];
            $fleet->parking_time = $attr['parking_time'];
            $fleet->spent_fuel = $attr['spent_fuel'];
            $fleet->remain_fuel = $attr['remain_fuel'];
            $fleet->distance = $attr['distance'];

            $fleet->save();`

Comment: И всё заработало.

Answer (score 1):

Как я писал в коде, но забыл упомянуть, я использовал две модели Report и Fleet.
Решением оказалось скопировать правила валидации в Fleet. Код пришёл к виду:

```
$model = new Fleet();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {


        $model->save();
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('reportFormSubmitted');
        return $this->refresh();
    }
```